Error OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig API .NET Framework 4.7.2
I am working on an API in .NET using Net Framework 4.7.2 which is compatible with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, I already have everything done, controllers, models and the respective classes that run using the controllers in their call.
The problem I have is that when testing in postman I get an error message:
[{“Error”: “1”, “Message”: “An exception occurred in the ‘OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig’ type initializer.”}]
This error comes from the exception of:
public static List<MensajeCursor> AccesoUsuario (UserLogin request)
{
    List<MensajeCursor> Cursor = new List<MensajeCursor>();
    try
    {
       cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Conection.getConnection();
        cmd.CommandText = "MYQUERY";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_User", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = request.User;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Pass", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = request.Pass;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_App", OracleDbType.Int32, int.MaxValue).Value = appNumber;

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Cursor.Add(new MensajeCursor()
            {
            Error = reader[0] == DBNull.Value ? "" : reader.GetString(0),
            Message = reader[1] == DBNull.Value ? "" : reader.GetString(1)
            });
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Cursor.Add(new MensajeCursor()
        {
            Error = "1",
            Message = ex.Message // Returned Error
        });
    }
    return Cursor;
}

Is there any way to know why it happens?
This is my list of packages used (without problems with the version and compatibility):

This is my web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"  maxRequestLength="102400"/> <!-- 100 MB Aprox -->
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <!-- <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /> 
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />-->
        </handlers>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Login.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" /> <!-- 100 MB -->
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.23.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DB_CONN" connectionString="MY DATA SOURCE"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

If you need additional info let me know.

Oracle is very sensitive to the version or the database and the version of the driver. When the wrong driver is used normally you will get a ORA error.  You code is not even initializing which means the connection string is wrong or the data provider is wrong.  Do you have the Oracle Driver 4.122.23.1 installed?  You need a version of the driver which is both compatible with Net 4.7.2 and compatible with the Oracle Database version.  See https://docs.oracle.com/health-sciences/inform-621/install/index.htm?toc.htm?222391.htm

The problem is in the compatibility of the installed packages, that's why I got the error, the solution was to read the documentation and compatibility of each of the packages because for each version have some packages where they depended on others, in short, the problem of the versions of the packages and their dependencies.
Some of them:

DotNetCompilerPlatform (needed version 1.0.3).
Change to NetFramework 4.8

In short, the problem of package versions and their dependencies.
Also, thanks to @jdweng
